# npm install -g npm is not updating

Tags: node.js, npm

I cannot seem to update npm with npm install:

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0
$ sudo npm install -g npm@latest
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/bin/npx -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.7.1
updated 1 package in 11.905s
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Probably you have multiple `npm` installed in your system.

Answer (score 38):

What's the output of your `which npm`, I bet it is not `/usr/bin/npm`.

**UPDATE**:

So yours' at `/usr/local/bin/npm`, but the `npm` you just updated is at `/usr/bin/npm`. See the line `/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` for the hint.

Remove the installation at `/usr/local/bin/npm` and you'll be fine.

If you don't know how to do that, simply do

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm`

Comment: it's /usr/local/bin/npm

Comment: Then you have multiple installs of node or npm, at least one of which is  a non-standard install. Consider removing them all and installing node the standard way

Comment: I had to follow up this command by downloading npm from node website installer and it worked

Comment: I had the same issue.  You need an extra step.
1. Delete /usr/local/bin/npm by $ sudo rm /user/local/bin/npm
2. $ npm -v -> -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
3. $ hash -r
4. $ npm -v -> 7.19.0

I have the npm under User/{username}/.npm_global/bin/npm

Comment: Worked for me, I had installed Node via brew and the npm within that package had taken over.

Answer (score 19):

Use `hash -r` to make bash clear its cache and look at the path again for latest npm path.

Answer (score 9):

I had noted that after installing the update, I have the re-login to the shell too see the updated npm version.  Not sure why some ppl don't have to do this, but in my case, that's what I had to do.

Comment: same here on digitalocean droplets

Answer (score 1):

Npm will always use the version of npm installed with node. If you are running node update node first running:

```
$ sudo npm install -g n
```

And to install the latest stable node release)

```
$ sudo n latest
```

And then check your npm version again - it should be updated. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob,

1. Go to your root
2. Run which npm and see the root, I believe it will be "/usr/local/bin/npm"
3. Stay on your root and try to run `npm install -g npm@latest`
4. I bet you get "missing permissions..."
5. Stay on your root and run the command: (to give permissions)
   `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
6. And then run:
   `npm install -g npm@latest`

Now it should work, please try to run npm -v and see if it changed.

Goodluck :)